# casperjs: Howto get links that contain text?

Tags: casperjs

I try with that: but does not look to work

```
function getLinks(containText) {
    return casper.evaluate(function(containText) {
        var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
        return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function (e) {
            var href = e.getAttribute('href');
            console.log(href);
            if (href.indexOf(containText) !== -1) {
                return href;
            }
        });
    })
}
links = getLinks('intermediary');
require('utils').dump(links );
```

Also the console.log does not seem to work: can I use that inside a evaluate() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getLinks(containText) {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href');
    }).filter(function(e) {
        return e.indexOf(containText) !== -1;
    });
}

casper.start('file:///tmp/test.html', function() {
    var links = this.evaluate(getLinks, 'intermediary');
    require('utils').dump(links);
});

casper.run();
```

You are correct that `console.log` won't work within `evaluate()` since it is running inside the context of the web page's DOM: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#casper-evaluate

Here's a sample `/tmp/test.html` to show that the filtering works:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Here are some example pages.</p>
    <p><a href="intermediary">a link</a></p>
    <p><a href="click">click</a></p>
    <p><a href="this contains the string intermediary in it">other link</a></p>
    <p><a href="this does not contain string">yet another link</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the output:

```
[
    "intermediary",
    "this contains the string intermediary in it"
]
```